# tmap legend outside title font size adjusting

Tags: r, tmap

It 's not a reprex.
I have maps with very long titles. I put my legend them outside. The font size is very small and I can't control it. The argument `title.size = 2` is not working.

```
 map_cp <- tm_shape(choro) +
        tm_polygons(col = "taux", style = "jenks",
                 legend.hist = TRUE) +
        tm_borders("#9E9E9E") +
  tm_shape(sgf_centro) +
  tm_symbols(col = "#f50057", alpha = 0.1, border.col = "#f50057",
  size = centro_var,
  perceptual = TRUE,
  scale = 2) +
   tm_layout(title = label$LIBELLE, title.size = 0.6,legend.outside = TRUE) 

map_cp
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution : using `main.title` function.

```
 map_cp <- tm_shape(choro) +
     tm_polygons(col = "taux", style = "jenks",
                 legend.hist = TRUE) +
     tm_borders("#9E9E9E") +
tm_shape(sgf_centro) +
tm_symbols(col = "#f50057", alpha = 0.1, border.col = "#f50057", size = 
 sgf_var, perceptual =TRUE, scale = 2) +
tm_layout(main.title = label$LIBELLE, main.title.size = 1,legend.outside = TRUE) 


 print(map_cp)
```

[image]